# Can't enable run retries for Dagster on Windows with SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, logging, dagster

I am running dagster-webserver 1.4.16 on Windows Server 2016 with SQL Server. I just tried enabling run retries in dagster.yaml but got hit with the following error message when I tried to run dagster-webserver on console:

*dagster._check.CheckError: Invariant failed. Description: Run retries are enabled, but the configured event log storage does not support them. Consider switching to Postgres or Mysql.*

I can't switch to Postgres or MySQL as my company is all-in on SQL Server. Does anybody have any ideas about configuring Dagster to use SQL Server or simply use local storage for event logs? I wonder if there is a way to bypass the Postgres/MySQL requirement entirely.

I have looked in the Dagster source code for possibly overriding the existing methods for event logs but haven't found an easy way of doing this.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am looking to do the exact same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Yeah - I figured. Why use open source when you can use the better solution, MSSQL?

Comment: Not going to argue which one is better, but why not accommodate one of the most popular databases in the world?

Comment: @cpowr why not ask Microsoft why SQL Server 2022 has almost no new features, unless it's only for Azure migrations? Why SSIS, SSRS and SSAS, the entire BI stack, are essentially deprecated, making the cost a lot higher for a lot less? Why doesn't Microsoft itself help with SQL Server support for eg dbt, unless it's for the *Azure* SKUs? Just in case you think that's grumbling, I was a SQL Server MVP. Also check Brent Ozar's [The Real Problem with SQL Server’s Licensing Costs](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2023/11/the-real-problem-with-sql-servers-licensing-costs/)

Comment: @cpowr if MS corporate (not the devs) thought they could charge for Dagster+Azure SQL they'd provide better support. It's easier to just charge for Azure PostgreSQL though. They do offer [Managed Airflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concept-managed-airflow) as an alternative to ADF Pipelines.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos pardon my ignorance, but are you suggesting this is an issue of MSSQL not accommodating Dagster, and not the other way around? Ditto with dbt, which I also frequently use, and am frustrated about.